# Extremely biased comment allowed to exist, all rebuttles removed

Tags: discussion

Alexander's comment on this answer https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/29883/6594 is extremely biased, has had attempted rebuts many times, all have been blown away but the original comment left.

Original two comments should be blown away with the rest. They're duplicated in the chat anyway.

Flag isn't getting it done.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry, but I don't see what's "extremely biased" about that comment. It just replies to a comment, links to a relevant other question which is useful for putting the answer into context and summarizes the answers to the linked question.

Comment: Then don't delete the attempted rebuts either.

Comment: It seems that comment has since been edited. Can you clarify why after initially holding firm on the issue, it seems the moderators caved to these demands?

Comment: @Joshua Perhaps you'd prefer to jot down those rebuttals into a proper answer to show what you believe is the unbiased and correct position? Comments are after all supposed to be nuked, This is a QA site, not a discussion forum as I am sure you are aware

Comment: @NSNoob: This wasn't a biased answer. This was a biased comment. Whoever edited away the summary should post answer here so I can accept it.